# Подскажите как поправить блоки по центру, они уходят вправо, как исправить?

Tags: html, css, inline-block

```css
.inthis{

width:80%;
border:2px solid gray;
background:silver;
box-shadow:0 0 10pt #727272;
padding:10pt;
border-radius:4pt;}
.block{
margin:10pt;
padding:10pt;
border:2px solid red;
border-radius:4pt;
width:235px;
height:335px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;}
/*
для любимого IE блокам с классом block добавляем
     _display:inline;
     *display:inline;
*/
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.2.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<header>
<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-header">
<div class="nav-title">
<a class="logo navItem active" aria-current="page" href="/" style="display:block;margin:20px;"><img src="" alt="img" style="filter: invert(0);float:left;width:6rem;margin:7px 7px 7px -7px;margin-top: -7px;"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<body>
<div class="inthis">
<? foreach($ano as $an){
?>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">1</div>
<? } ?>
</div>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
css
.inthis{
   display:flex;
   flex-flow: column;  
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]